# How to stop div from hiding on clicking submit button?

Tags: jquery, html

I Have a dropdown list with the values "AAA" and "BBB".On selecting "AAA",it shows a hidden div which have two text box and submit button.The problem for me is once i fill the data in textbox and click submit,the page loads and the div disappears.I dont want the div to be hidden.Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrongly,Please provide me a example if possble.Thanks in advance

Dropdown list

```
<select id= "purpose"  name="purpose" size="50px"  style="margin-top:30px">

 <option value="1" 
   <%
   if request.form("purpose") = "1" then 
       response.write("selected") 
      end if %>
         >SELECT</option>
          <option value="2" 
          <%
    if request.form("purpose") = "2" then 
        response.write("selected") 
       end if %>
      >AAA</option>
   <option value="3" 
     <%
       if request.form("purpose") = "3" then 
        response.write("selected") 
     end if %>
   >BBB</option>
     </select>
        </div>
```

Script to show/hide div

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#purpose').on('change', function () {
            if (this.value == "1") {
              $(".AAA").hide();
                $(".BBB").hide();
              }
            else { }
            if (this.value == '2') 
            {
                $(".AAA").show();
      }
            else {
                $(".AAA").hide();

               }
            if (this.value == '3') {
                $(".BBB").show();
                }
            else {
                $(".BBB").hide();
               }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is on page load the div visibility is not set based on the selected option for that one solution is to manually trigger the change event so that the div visibility can be set based on the selected option

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#purpose').on('change', function () {
         if (this.value == "1") {
             $(".AAA").hide();
             $(".BBB").hide();
         } else {}
         if (this.value == '2') {
             $(".AAA").show();
         } else {
             $(".AAA").hide();

         }
         if (this.value == '3') {
             $(".BBB").show();
         } else {
             $(".BBB").hide();
         }
     }).change();
 });
```

---

Your entire script can be simplified as below using [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#purpose').on('change', function () {
        $(".AAA").toggle(this.value == '2');
        $(".BBB").toggle(this.value == '3');
    }).change();
});
```